# Record everything what you hear from your soundcard

Tags: sound, audio-recording

How can I record everything, I hear on my desktop?

I would like to record some sounds, I hear on a website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not tell us what version and edition of Ubuntu you are using. I am assuming that you are using standard Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.

- Install PulseAudio Volume Control:

  ```
  sudo apt install pavucontrol
  ```
- If you haven't done so already, install your preferred sound recording application; I will use Audacity for demonstration purposes.
- Open PulseAudio Volume Control, go to the "Recoding" tab, make sure that the selector is to show "Applications". The window will be empty, saying that no application is currently recording audio. Let it be.
- Open your sound recording application and start recording.
- In the PulseAudio Volume Control window notice that your application has been listed as recording audio; select "Monitor of <your-sound-card>" as the source.
- The selection will be remembered.

[image: Screenshot of Audacity recoding with PulseAudio Volume Control in the background]